# JQuery sortable shift-clone with output object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hey awesome problem solvers, Here is a problem I need help with:

I have multiple lists that I am using JQuery Sortable to sort with, and then output an object of the changed list.  One feature that I need help with is having a shift-copy from one list to the other. This would keep the original in it's list, and then place the clone element into the new list, where it was dropped.

Getting that far hasn't been too much of a problem.  But when I create the object for output, it rarely matches up with what we visually see on the screen.  The list items are not in the proper order, and sometimes there are extra copies of the cloned list item.

[Here is the JS Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/yYKmw/6/)

```
<ul  class="sortable" data-name="List 1">
    <p>List 1</p>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 7</li>
</ul>

<ul  class="sortable" data-name="List 2">
    <p>List 2</p>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 7</li>
</ul>
<p style="clear: both">Output Object</p>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Here is the Javascript/jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({

        connectWith: ".sortable",

            activate: function (event, ui) {
            if (event.shiftKey == true) {
            $('body').css('cursor', 'copy');
                }
            },

            stop: function(event, ui) {
            if (event.shiftKey == true) {
                return false;
                }
            },

            receive: function(event, ui) {
            if (event.shiftKey == true) {
                ui.item.clone().appendTo($(this)); 
                }
            },

            update: function(event, ui) {
            sendList(ui.item.closest('ul'));
            },


    });<!-- end Jquery Sortable -->
  });<!-- end function -->

 // function for output
 function sendList(list) {
        var listArray = [];
        var ulObject={};

     // iterate through the list and push html into array
        list.find('li').each(function(index, element) {
            listArray.push( $(this).html() );
        });

     // update object
        ulObject = {
            "List Name" : list.attr('data-name'),
            "List Items" : listArray
        }

    console.log(ulObject);
        $('#output').html("").append( JSON.stringify(ulObject, "", "\r\n" ));

    }
```

And for aesthetic-ness: The CSS:

```
.sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 1em; padding: 0; width: 30%; float: left;}
.sortable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; height: 12px; }
#output {clear:both; border: thin solid black; padding: 1em; margin: 1em; width: 60%; min-height: 250px}
p {clear:both; margin-left: 1em;}
```

Comment: When I play with your code on jsfiddle everything works fine, can you detail the steps you take to produce the bug you are talking about? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is shift dragging one list item to the next list, and having the output come through correctly. In the original fiddle the destination list would have the shift-dragged item in the wrong spot, and the output field would show that item in three places.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in the next fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yYKmw/7/

Basically, the sortable bind functions at the bottom allow the shift-drag item to be placed into the new list properly. (this solution was found in another stackoverflow post that I cannot find at the moment).

That combined with not using the ui.item.clone().appendTo($(this)); on the sortable receive did the trick, but I'm still open to other suggestions.

```
  $(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({

        connectWith: ".sortable",

            activate: function (event, ui) {
            if (event.shiftKey == true) {
            $('body').css('cursor', 'copy');
                }
            },

            stop: function(event, ui) {
            if (event.shiftKey == true) {
                return false;
                }
            },

            receive: function(event, ui) {
            if (event.shiftKey == true) {
                //ui.item.clone().appendTo($(this)); 
                }
            },

            update: function(event, ui) {
            sendList($(this).closest('ul'));
            },


    });<!-- end Jquery Sortable -->
  });<!-- end function -->


      $('.sortable').bind('sortstop', function(event, ui) {
            var idx = $('.sortable').children().index($(ui.item[0]))-1,
                elm = $(ui.item[0]).clone(true);
     $('.sortable').children(':eq('+idx+')').after(elm);
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
    });
```